# Ошибка при установке Яндекс.Танк

Tags: яндекс-танк

Столкнулся с ошибкой при установке приложения. Согласно официальному мануалу нужно выполнить команду:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install yandex-tank
```

Получаю ошибку:

> Пакеты, имеющие неудовлетворённые зависимости:
>    yandex-tank : Зависит: python-requests (>= 2.5.1) но 2.2.1-1ubuntu0.3 будет установлен
>   E: Невозможно исправить ошибки, у вас отложены (held) битые пакеты.

Подскажите как побороть ?
У меня Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. Вижу что версия не та, но под мою версию Ubuntu этот максимум:
https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/requests

Comment: Не подскажешь как это сделал "Из положения вышел не самым сложным методом - установил принудительно через pip."
Только начинаю разбираться с Ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

Баг, есть баг. Пошурашл интернет (не останавливаясь на русско язычных комьюнити) нового ничего не узнал. Кто то уже сталкивался, результат такой же как у меня. Из положения вышел не самым сложным методом - установил принудительно через pip.

Answer (score 0):

Вот

```
pip install requests --upgrade
```

Только скорее всего он попросит обновить pip, но предлагаемая команда появится в консоли